# Windows 7 documentation for how folder time stamp changes?

Tags: windows, file, timestamp, directory

I am looking for official documentation (preferably) that would describe when exactly Windows folder time-stamp changes. I am not sure where to look for the exact answer and any help will be appreciated.

The problem is that there is a folder in which all of the files have "changed" date coming from say 2005 while the folder changed date is 2015. What actions could (except for deleting / moving files) could have brought that change to the folder time stamp? Unfortunately I do not have access to complete metadata but only to the date of last change (screenshot).

Thanks a lot for any tip!

Comment: There's detailed information in [File System Behavior Overview](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/3/8/43889780-8d45-4b2e-9d3a-c696a890309f/File%20System%20Behavior%20Overview.pdf) (PDF) that might help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - but thanks a lot!